# Get current sheet in Time-Based trigger event for multiple existing sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm developing a script that write to sheet, trigger type is [time-based](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

My problem is I don't know the target sheet to write into, because I cannot use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()`

My workflow:

- I have 5 sheets that need to write data into every 1 hours
- Add 1 hours trigger to 5 sheets, my `onHours()` function will be triggered every hours
- write to range `A1:B2` of a sheet

So how can I get the current triggered sheet Id?

Comment: Your issue is not very clear to me. Can you show your code and explain more in detail what the problem is. Do you know the Id of the spreadsheet and the names of the sheets?

Comment: Try using SpreadsheetApp.openById()

Comment: @ziganotschka I want to get the current sheet Id that the script is running on, I have 5 sheets, 4 were cloned from sheet 1 with script. When the script was triggered in time-based manner, I wanna get the active sheetId
Thank @#Cooper but it's not my intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As investigated, I figure out how the clone process works:

- Assuming you have 1 google sheet call **Sheet 1**, that sheet has a google app script that does "hello world"
- You "make copy" (clone) **Sheet 2** from **Sheet 1**

Now, **Sheet 1** is having "hello world" script, **Sheet 2** is having "hello world" script too, but the difference is:

> The script ID of sheet 1 and sheet 2 is not identical, it mean Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 has not using same script, the script in sheet 2 is just a new copy of the script in Sheet 1. 
>   You can modify the script content of to "hello world 2" without any affecting the original script "hello world"

---

According to the above investigation, my solution is:

Get the current running sheetId by `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()`